# Accessing elements using a dynamic id selector in Jquery

Tags: jquery

I am trying to refer elements in my view with `id` attribute using `jquery` as seen in the code below.

**HTML**

```
<div id="abc"></div>
<div id="def"></div>
<div id="ghi"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function prependMarkup(idName, markup) {
    $('#' + idName).prepend(markup);
};
```

So i am passing the id's in the function above but it does not seem to work. The markup is being written inside the div as text.

Comment: what you mean by `as text` ?

Comment: Please include the rest of your jquery code

Comment: After giving the function a name(like ```function foo(idName, markup)```) the code works fine for me

Comment: function missing a name!!

Answer (score 1):

The code you provided isn't valid. You have to assign a funtion name in order to make the JS work.

```
function foo(idName, markup) {
$('#' + idName).prepend(markup);
};
```

Please do look into errors yourself next time, for example by doing a [syntax check](http://www.jslint.com/). Also, have a look at [How to post a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a jQuery Library and use `html()` instead of `prepend()`.
This will help you to show the html instead of text.

Also Your Function missing a function name.

```js
function funcname(idName, markup) {
    $('#' + idName).html(markup);
};


funcname('abc','<div class="jaba">ABCD</div>')
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<div id="abc"></div>
<div id="def"></div>
<div id="ghi"></div>
```